# Undefined Javascript variable, but I don't understand why

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm currently working on a project in which I try to get a whole settings form to auto-save itself using Ajax. I've got basically this setup in the project's directory (only files related to this issue are shown):

```
/FireGuard/
 |-> headincludes.php
 |-> index.php
 |-> settings.php
 |-> settingsupdate.php
 |-> settings.json
```

The settings.php file, as well as headincludes.php are included into index.php using PHP includes. The headincludes.php file contains a Javascript function called settingsUpdater() that sends the form via a GET request to settingsupdate.php, which wraps all the values into settings.json.
Problem is that calling settingsUpdater(alarmonoff,mailnotifications,smsnotifications,firstname,lastname,username,email,phone); gives this error in the web console:

> [15:30:17.807] TypeError: alarmonoff is undefined

Here are the different source codes you could need to understand this.

headincludes.php:

```
<!-- Ajax Request function -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var alarmonoff = $('#alarmonoff:checked').val();
    var emailnotifications = $('#emailnotifications:checked').val();
    var smsnotifications = $('#smsnotifications:checked').val();
    var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
    var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var phone = $('#phone').val();

    function settingsUpdater(alarmonoff,mailnotifications,smsnotifications,firstname,lastname,username,email,phone) {
        if (alarmonoff.checked) {
            var alarmonoffstate = "on";
        }

        else {
            var alarmonoffstate = "null";
        }

        if (mailnotifications.checked) {
            var mailnotificationsstate = "on";
        }

        else {
            var mailnotificationsstate = "null";
        }

        if (smsnotifications.checked) {
            var smsnotificationsstate = "on";
        }

        else {
            var smsnotificationsstate = "null";
        }

        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET","settingsupdate.php?alarmonoffstate="+alarmonoffstate+"&mailnotificationsstate="+mailnotificationsstate+"&smsnotificationsstate="+smsnotificationsstate+"&firstname="+firstname+"&lastname="+lastname+"&username="+username+"&email="+email+"&phone="+phone,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

settingsupdate.php:

```
<?php
    $settings = array(
        'alarmonoff' => $_GET['alarmonoffstate'],
        'mailnotifications' => $_GET['mailnotificationsstate'],
        'smsnotifications' => $_GET['smsnotificationsstate']
        'firstname' => $_GET['firstname']
        'lastname' => $_GET['lastname']
        'username' => $_GET['username']
        'email' => $_GET['email']
        'phone' => $_GET['phone']
    );
    echo("Array ok: \n");
    echo(var_dump($settings));
    echo("\n");
    $jsonsettings = json_encode($settings);
    echo("JSON Encode ok: \n");
    echo($jsonsettings);
    echo("\n");
    $handle = fopen("settings.json","w") or die("Fopen not working");
    echo("fopen ok: \n");
    echo($handle);
    echo("\n");
    fwrite($handle, $jsonsettings) or die("Fwrite not working");
    echo("fwrite ok \n");
    fclose($handle) or die("Fclose not working");
    echo("fclose ok \n");
?>
```

settings.php (it's a bit long, sorry, but I guess it's better to upload the whole file):

```
    <?php
    $handle = fopen("./settings.json","r");
    $settings = fread($handle, 512);
    $jsonsettings = json_decode($settings, true);
    extract($jsonsettings);
    fclose($handle);

    function alarmonoffcheck () {
        global $alarmonoff;
        if ($alarmonoff == "on") {
            echo("checked");
        }
    }

    function emailnotifcheck () {
        global $mailnotifications;
        if ($mailnotifications == "on") {
            echo("checked");
        }
    }

    function smsnotifcheck () {
        global $smsnotifications;
        if ($smsnotifications == "on") {
            echo("checked");
        }
    }

    global $firstname;
    global $lastname;
    global $username;
    global $email;
    global $phone;
?>
<section id="settings" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-sm-3">
            <ul id="settingsmenu" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="active"><a href="#general" data-toggle="tab">General</a></li>
                <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#detection" data-toggle="tab">Detection</a></li>
                <li><a href="#network" data-toggle="tab">Network</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <section class="tab-content">
                <section id="general" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                    <h2>General settings</h2>
                    <form class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="control-group row">
                            <label class="switch-label col-sm-5 control-label" for="alarmonoff">Alarm/Detection</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="switch-wrapper">
                                    <input onChange="settingsUpdater(alarmonoff,mailnotifications,smsnotifications,firstname,lastname,username,email,phone);" id="alarmonoff" name="alarmonoff" type="checkbox" <?php alarmonoffcheck(); ?>>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group row">
                            <label class="switch-label col-sm-5 control-label" for="mailnotifications">Email Notifications</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="switch-wrapper">
                                    <input onChange="settingsUpdater(alarmonoff,mailnotifications,smsnotifications,firstname,lastname,username,email,phone);" id="mailnotifications" name="mailnotifications" type="checkbox" <?php emailnotifcheck(); ?>>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group row">
                            <label class="switch-label col-sm-5 control-label" for="smsnotifications">SMS Notifications</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 switch-master-wrapper">
                                <div class="switch-wrapper">
                                    <input onChange="settingsUpdater(alarmonoff,mailnotifications,smsnotifications,firstname,lastname,username,email,phone);" id="smsnotifications" name="smsnotifications" type="checkbox" <?php smsnotifcheck(); ?>>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </section>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $("input#alarmonoff").switchButton();
                    $("input#mailnotifications").switchButton();
                    $("input#smsnotifications").switchButton();
                </script>
                <section id="profile" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h2>Your profile</h2>
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="firstname" class="control-label">First name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" value="<?php echo($firstname); ?>" onkeypress="settingsUpdater(alarmonoff,mailnotifications,smsnotifications,firstname,lastname,username,email,phone);">
                                    <label for="lastname" class="control-label">Last name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" value="<?php echo($lastname); ?>" onkeypress="settingsUpdater(alarmonoff,mailnotifications,smsnotifications,firstname,lastname,username,email,phone);">
                                </div>

                                <div id="profilepiccontainer" class="col-sm-4">
                                    <label class="filebutton" style="background-image: url('noprofilepic.png'), url('overlay.png'); background-size: cover;">
                                        <span><input type="file" id="profilepicbrowser" name="profilepic"></span>
                                    </label>
                                    <!-- <img id="profilepic" class="img-thumbnail" src="noprofilepic.png" width="125px" /> -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- <div  class="col-sm-4">
                                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                        Browse <input type="file">
                                    </span>
                                </div> -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" value="<?php echo($username); ?>" onkeypress="settingsUpdater(alarmonoff,mailnotifications,smsnotifications,firstname,lastname,username,email,phone);">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" value="<?php echo($email); ?>" onkeypress="settingsUpdater(alarmonoff,mailnotifications,smsnotifications,firstname,lastname,username,email,phone);">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone number</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" value="<?php echo($phone); ?>" onkeypress="settingsUpdater(alarmonoff,mailnotifications,smsnotifications,firstname,lastname,username,email,phone);">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </section>
                <section id="detection" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h1>Detection settings</h1>
                </section>
                <section id="network" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h1>Detection tab</h1>
                </section>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I've been Googling and modifying my code for a while trying to find an answer but I still don't understand this error.

A very warm thank you in advance to the person who'll get to find where it is from!

Comment: Why are you passing them as parameters to that function while they are global? They can be reached by the function itself, so why pass them along?

Comment: It seems like your `script` tag is running before the page has fully loaded. What happens if you change that `script` tag to be the last element inside your `body`?

Comment: `alarmonoff` is a global variable, a local variable and a function parameter. Are they supposed to be three different entities, or you're just misusing the `var` keyword?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: it's a global PHP variable (completely independant from the rest of the code as it contains the value for the checkbox, that is fetched on the page loading) and a Javascript variable, which is used as a function parameter yes :).

Comment: I don't know why, but now I don't get this error anymore, I get a 500 Internal Server Error instead (still in the web console).

Comment: @Llepwryd: It doesn't change anything :/